# Can a very long screen display an object travelling faster than light?

Tags: speed-of-light

I know information is not allowed to travel faster than light. Now suppose we have a very long screen displaying a moving light dot. Can the screen display the light dot which travels faster than light?

Comment: The question I've linked is about the spot from a laser sweeping across the Moon, but it is basically the same question and has the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the dot is not physically moving, and there is no information traveling from one pixel to the next. The screen can even display many dots at the same time without any problem.